# Using $_FILES in php after AJAX upload

Tags: javascript

I have tried out multiple solutions but none of them have worked for me so far so I would greatly appreciate help with this!

Comment: you can use $_FILES["name"] it will work

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad that shows Undefined index name

Comment: what is the name of your file field name?

Comment: $_FILES['image']["name"]

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad the file field name is 'fileName'. But I also tried $_FILES['fileName']["name"] and it doesn't work either.

Comment: this work you need to debug your code, as your code to much i can not test it so you need to debug by dumping the $_POST you will get the idea

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad When I do var_dump($_FILES), I get an empty array. But when I do var_dump($_POST), I get ["tags"]=>string(29) "["john.doe@gmail.com"]", ["fileName"]=>string(8) "test.txt". I am trying to move the uploaded file to a temporary folder afterwards so I need to access whole file. Can I do that just with $_POST instead of using $_FILES?

Comment: can you try this one please and then dump the files let userFile = new FormData($('#userFile')[0]);
data: userFile,

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad it is still empty

Comment: Then try to debug you form data it have some issues

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be checking for `$_FILES['fileName']` instead.

Comment: this shows undefined index fileName when I remove the if statement. If I keep it, the code inside doesn't get executed